# Am I misinterpreting conjunctive normal form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am reading through Wolf's *A Tour Through Mathematical Logic* and I encountered Chapter 1.2 Example 6, which states: "The statement 
[(P $\rightarrow$ ~Q) $\iff$ (R $\lor$ ~P)] 
has the conjunctive normal form equivalent 
[(P$\lor$Q$\lor$R) $\land$ (~P$\lor$Q$\lor$R) $\land$ (~P$\lor$~Q$\lor$~R)]."
This confuses me: when I draw out the truth tables, I find that they differ when P, Q, and R are all false: in this case, the first statement is true while the second is false. Is there a facet of these definitions that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: In the CNF form, all three conjuncts, each of which is a disjunct of three literals, must hold at once. If P,Q,R all false, then the first conjunct PvQvR does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given in the book is incorrect as your argument about the values when the three variables are all false shows. A correct CNF for $(P \rightarrow {\sim} Q) \iff (R \lor {\sim}P)$ is $({\sim}P \lor Q \lor R) \land ({\sim P} \lor {\sim} Q \lor {\sim} R)$. I.e., the first conjunct in Wolf's answer shouldn't be there.